# How to add a class to elements in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, class, daterangepicker

```
function dateRange(startDate, endDate, steps = 1) {
    const dateArray = [];
    let currentDate = new Date(startDate);

    while (currentDate <= new Date(endDate)) {
        dateArray.push(new Date(currentDate));
        currentDate.setUTCDate(currentDate.getUTCDate() + steps);
    }
    return dateArray;
}
```

I need to add a class for each element of the array so that I can change the background color of those dates that are in that range between start and end date. I tried through `e.target`, but it does not work because it's an array of dates.

Comment: Only DOM elements have CSS classes, so you would need to put your dates inside some DOM elements, or create new DOM elements to display your dates in.

Comment: I tried and failed
Would you perhaps write how to do it?

Comment: What does the corresponding html look like?

Comment: Provide your codes completely. The renderer script.